# How do I calculate the path of total eclipse?

Tags: pyephem

After observing the total eclipse on 20th March, 2015, I got to thinking about calculating the path of total eclipse using pyephem.

My general approach is to calculate the time and location of greatest eclipse, then work backward and forward from that point. By starting with the greatest eclipse parameters, I could check it against this:

[image: Total solar eclipse of 2015 March 20]

So given the time, the RA/dec of the moon and the sun, how would I go about calculating the latitude and longitude of greatest eclipse?

Comment: Might this fit better to http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: You can compute the separation between the two bodies and find when it hits its minimum value. This can be done using the **ephem.separation()** function.